# How do I create a struct?

Tags: matlab

How do I create an array in struct to keep track of all my_exp?

My code

```
my_exp=struct(x, y);
for i = 1:32
    my_exp.x= i;
    my_exp.y= i*i;
end
my_exp
```

Comment: @Adriaan I think the duplicate you picked is incorrect. The question wasn't about an array of structures, but an array *in* a struct

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you initialize your structure properly.
You want to do:

```
my_exp=struct('x',[],'y',[])
for i = 1:32
  my_exp.x= [my_exp.x i];
  my_exp.y= [my_exp.x i*i];
end
my_exp
```

Comment: This solved the issue of it not running but how do I prevent the for loop from over writing the old values?

Comment: @asasasasas you want an array of structs? just do that then!

Comment: @asasasasas See edit